# BootStrap dropdown in wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal and in the modals body I want to add a dropdown button.

But for some reason the drop down is in the complete wrong place and I have tried over writing it in the css but to no avail

I tried this first

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <h2 align="left"><img src="/pic"width="50px" height="50px" />Share</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="textarea" align="left" id = "shareSearchBar"  placeholder ="" name = "search">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <img src="pic2"width="20px" height="20px" />Edit
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu  " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />V</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

With my css trying to move the button in the correct position which it does.

```
#dropdownMenu1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    right: 3%
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    right: 0%
}
```

Then I tried the follwoing which is very similar but a bit different

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <button type="button" id = "dropdownMenu1" class="btn btn-small btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      <img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />Edit
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#" data-value="action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />e</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="another action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />v</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same css...

I really can't see anyway about this.

[image]

Comment: You need fiddle for this so we can replicate

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the dropdown is in the wrong position.  Does it look like the image you posted?  Are you trying to have the dropdown button on the side of the input and the dropdown menu is showing up in the wrong spot?  Or is there something else you are trying to do?  Can you please clarify a little so we can help you.  Here is a fiddle that I have made is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/hcgd9u43/

Comment: @DrinkinPeople I am trying to do exactly what you have done there. Yes it does look like the image I posted. See I created my own custom modal view without using the bootstrap. I have a feeling that is whats going on, but it shouldnt be

Comment: What is probably happening is that when you put the position of absolute to your dropdown the dropdown menu is not wrapped in a relative container anymore and is going to the next container which is the fixed modal.  Try removing the absolute positioning from your css and do like I did in the fiddle.  Put an extra class of modal-dropdown to the .dropdown so other dropdowns in the rest of your site are not affected and give this class a css of display: inline-block and see if that works.  Or use bootstrap's input groups would be better stll.  If it does I will post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

@hat_to_the_back: here is updated the fiddle that @Drinking People made.. fits what you want to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/Jyde/hcgd9u43/2/

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />Edit <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#" data-value="action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />e</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-value="another action"><img src="/pic"width="20px" height="20px" />v</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you reinitiliaze your dropdown on show event of model. Something like this :

```
$('#mymodal').on('shown', function() {
        $("#mydropdown").dropdown();
    });
```

And remove your custom css.

Event and initiliaze syntax can change according to the version of bootstrap.

Comment: Note that bootstrap 3 requires `.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {`

Comment: maybe is other css affected.  they to remove all other css and purely bootstrap css and style. then slowly debug from top to bottom